# Why is the Tiger/German Suplex wrestling move so popular among anime culture?

Tags: tropes, culture

I see a lot of fan art that depict this move (even though nothing of the sort happens from the show/series where the characters came from) and even in Nichijou we have the school principal giving a deer a tiger suplex:

[image]

[Shuichi drops a suplex in Gravitation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su38Cn-Ict4)

[GTO dishes one out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auRmEQ1c_ro#t=0m20)

Episode 87 of Gintama is: "Perform a German Suplex On a Woman Who Asks If She or the Job Is More Important"

From Lagrange, the mechas do one:
[image]

And all the endless fanart:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is this so popular? Is this because wrestling is popular in Japan? But why this specific move?

Comment: lol, I can't stop watching the gif :P

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall That [whole sequence is hilarious](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7Et0a8fnuw), and it doesn't make a lick of sense

Comment: Because it's so brutal and yet, funny? XD

Comment: I guess is because the video of a woman using it to stop a thief:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4xpOsCcWIw‎

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The instance from GTO predates that video.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's very likely because of the popularity of *[puroresu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puroresu)* (wrestling) in Japan. [Antonio Inoki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Inoki) is credited with making wrestling popular in the country and he himself was impressed with and inspired by the amateur wrestling style of [Karl Gotch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Gotch) (nicknamed *Kami-sama*) who had become famous in Japan. The German suplex was Gotch's signature finishing move.

[image]

There's a [compilation of Gotch's moves](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZqKEVTGZPc) on YouTube.

Comment: Yeah, this is why, friend had confirmed it a few hours ago when I asked. He also said none of these moves are a "tiger" suplex which is a double underhook.